# Detect target phone number on incoming call is it for SIM 1 or for SIM 2 for Android 29+?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-phone-call

1. I have tried all of the stack overflow solutions but it didn't work, all solutions are outdated
2. I tried both below codes but it always return the `-1`

> int slot =  intent.getExtras().getInt("slot",-1)

> int slot =  intent.getExtras().getInt("simId", -1)

Comment: You need to edit your question with more code ... I am not sure how the calls that you are making should give you the result ... might be a typo in your code  I guess

Answer (score 1):

```
val accounts = telecomManager.callCapablePhoneAccounts

if (accounts.size > 1) {

                accounts.forEachIndexed { index, account ->
                    if (account == CallManager.call.last()?.details?.accountHandle) {

                        val phoneAccount = telecomManager.getPhoneAccount(account)
                        val label = phoneAccount.label.toString()

                        val img: Drawable =
                            resources.getDrawable(sims[index], theme)
}
```

Try using this method with `telecomManager` you can find the sim on which you are receiving call.

Comment: Hi @Tariq Hussain, can u assist me to solve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/76097725/5197712